# Split character in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel file with version number column. The content of the column is for example: 70001, 70002.
What I want to do is to create another column refer to that column, and have the value to be 7.0.0.0.1, 7.0.0.0.2.

Any idea how to do it in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are in the column A you can use the following formula in the next column:
=MID(A1;1;1)&"."&MID(A1;2;1)&"."&MID(A1;3;1)&"."&MID(A1;4;1)&"."&MID(A1;5;1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is in cell A2, use the formula:

```
    =MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
     SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
     A2,"0",".0"),"1",".1"),"2",".2"),"3",".3"),"4",".4"),"5",".5"),"6",".6"),"7",".7"),
     "8",".8"),"9",".9"),2,50)
```

which does a text replace for every single digit 1-9 with period plus digit, and at the end removes the first period by taking the substring from the second char.

Sorry.

Comment: Your formula doesn't work when I try it. Error: `you've entered too few arguments for this function`.  In Excel, `REPLACE` has four arguments; looks like you only show two; and `SUBSTR` is not an Excel function in English Excel 2016

Comment: I used a German Excel 2007, and guessed the English function names. Researched a bit and found the correct translations. Edited

Comment: Thought it might be a language problem.  Works fine now with numeric input and, obviously, will work on older versions of Excel also, unlike mine.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It still is a ridiculous solution.

Comment: :-) But there are some places in the US where the IT department prevents use of VBA (without an extensive approval process), so an Excel based solution can be of value, even if limited in application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to copy the cell, and then split it using Data | Text to Columns (fixed width, 1 line per character).   Now concatenate the whole thing in another column using "." in the middle of each reference.

E.g.

```
=a1 & "." & b1 & "." & c1
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about the length of the string, or if it varies, then you can use the below `VBA` function. It uses a `FOR` loop and take out each character and add a `.` to the end excepts last character. And at last concatenate the last character.

**VBA function**

```
Function version(str As Variant) As Variant
    Dim l As Integer
    l = Len(str)

    For i = 1 To l - 1
        version = version & Mid(str, i, 1) & "."
    Next i

    version = version & Right(str, 1)

End Function
```

Then use this function like, `=version(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016 with the `CONCAT` function, you can use the **array** formula:

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(A1),"." &MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&LEN(A1))),1))
```

This is an array formula and must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>